# how to query if point is inside a circle schema _ mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

this is my schema :

```
var schema = new Schema({
    loc: {
        type: {
            type: String
        },
        coordinates: []
    },
     radius : {
      type : 'Number'
     }
});
schema.index({
    loc: '2dsphere'
});
var A = mongoose.model('Circle', schema);
```

and this is my collection example:

```
{
 loc: {type : "Point", coordinates: [77.69866, 13.025621]}, radius: 100.21
}
```

my question is: is it possible to check if this point  **[12.1222, 29.2112]** is inside my Circle collection?

Comment: [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) at your disposal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#-geonear--aggregation-) aggregation stage.

```
Model.aggregate([
    {$geoNear: {
        near: {type:"Point", coordinates:[12.1222, 29.2112]},
        distanceField: "distance"
    }},
    {$match: {
       $expr: {$lt: ["$distance", "$radius"]}
    }}
])
```